# Passing data from the FirstViewController to the LastViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have four viewControllers in my current design and I am designing an app to sell a product.

`FirstViewController` gets the product image and when user clicks to the next button then it takes user to the `secondviewcontroller` where user describes the product and then user clicks next button which takes user to the `thirdViewcontroller` where price and condition are entered. In the `lastviewcontolller` there is a post button to send the product info to the server. I am using `POST` method.

The following segue approach does not fit into what I want, because it sends the `firstviewcontroller` object (product image) to the `secondviewcontoller`, and then `secondviewcontroller` also should forward the product image to the `thirdviewcontoller` and so on. I do not think it is a feasible way of doing it.

I wonder what is the best way of collection information from the first page till to the last page and send it. What is best way of handling that issue? I am using segue between the viewcontrollers.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"isSecond"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        SecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyProductImage:productImage];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **don't** use a singleton, even if the majority of users here tells you so. It would violate the [SOLID-Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) for several reasons.

Instead just pass the object from ViewController to ViewController.

If all ViewController expect the same model class, you can create a common base class that has the property for the model.

it could have this method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewControler isKindOfClass:[ProductAwareBaseViewController class]])
    {
        ProductAwareBaseViewController *vc = (ProductAwareBaseViewController *)segue.destinationViewControler;
        vc.product = self.product;
    }
}
```

---

I created an example project: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/ProductWizard

Note, that all view controller derive from `ProductAwareBaseViewController`

```
@import UIKit;

@class Product;

@interface ProductAwareBaseViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) Product *product;
@end
```

---

```
#import "ProductAwareBaseViewController.h"
#import "Product.h"

@interface ProductAwareBaseViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProductAwareBaseViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ProductAwareBaseViewController class]]) {
        ProductAwareBaseViewController *vc = (ProductAwareBaseViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.product = self.product;
    }
}
@end
```

This ViewController knows how to pass the model data of class `Product` to other instances of `ProductAwareBaseViewController` and subclasses of it.

All other view controller don't deal with passing the data, just adding each portion of data (name, description, price) to the model and displaying it.

i.e:

```
#import "EditNameProductViewController.h"
#import "Product.h"

@interface EditNameProductViewController () 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@end

@implementation EditNameProductViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.product = [[Product alloc] init]; 
}

- (IBAction)continueTapped:(id)sender {
    self.product.productName = self.nameField.text; 
}

@end
```

---

```
#import "EditDescriptionProductViewController.h"
#import "Product.h"

@interface EditDescriptionProductViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *descriptionField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@end

@implementation EditDescriptionProductViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.nameLabel.text = self.product.productName;
}

- (IBAction)continueTapped:(id)sender {
    self.product.productDescription = self.descriptionField.text;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks vikingosengundo, in your proposed design principal, each viewController object needs to pass the product information to its destination viewcontroller. Am I right? Could you please extend your code example ?

Comment: I am preparing an example

Answer (score 1):

Create an object to act as your application's data model.  It can be a singleton or it can be a normal object that's available from a known location...such as owned by the app delegate.

Update your model when you have new information and read from the model when you need to display something.  Using `prepareForSegue:` and linking controllers may be acceptable for simple things but it really doesn't scale well.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks a lot Philip for the quick answer, is there any recommended tutorials or examples that I could learn this methodology practically?

Comment: Phillip, I'd strongly recommend not suggesting to use the app delegate for passing data within an app. Not only is it improper usage of the app delegate but it can be a trap that can be difficult to escape from down the line and may conflict with future iOS changes.

Comment: @DanielZhang: I don't see it as improper any more than the app delegate being the initialization point for the view and controller portions of the application.  Having it as the primary owner of the model as well has a certain MVC symmetry.  (That being said, I only mention it because some people react badly to "singleton".)  As for conflict with iOS changes, unless you know some specific plans, that can be said about absolutely anything.

Comment: Phillip, I accept your point regarding symmetry and the app delegate is a good example of a singleton. It would have been more constructive for me to say that there is much to gain by not using the app delegate for global data, especially by less experienced developers. It can be easy to abuse thereby leading to the trap that I mentioned. I don’t know about any specific upcoming iOS changes but at least that concern is alleviated by not basing code in there.

Comment: Real issues with singleton: Global state -> messed up memory, memory rules of cocoa wont apply. hidden dependencies. hard to test. hard to mock. violation of OCP. violation of DIP. violation of LSP. and in case of using app delegate as an singleton: violation of SRP.

Comment: Somebody should create a new methodology and call it Jargon-Driven Development.  :)

Comment: if you dont know and respect the SOLID principles, I guess you are behind door two: http://blog.codinghorror.com/content/images/uploads/2009/02/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877707a45970c-pi.png

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be that you create a mutable dictionary (or a custom object with variables) in the first view controller. Then you would pass a weak reference to second/third/fourth view controllers of the mutable dictionary/object from first view controller. Each view controller would be able to set data to the dictionary/object and the last one would be able to process the information.

Another way would be to create a simple singleton class with variables that you want to store. The first view controller would reset the singleton variables. Then let each view controller access the singleton and store their values there, last view controller would process values from singleton.

It depends how many data you are collecting and what you personally prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot haluzak for the quick answer, is there a good tutorial or example that I could learn this methodology practically?

Comment: @texas you can learn about the Singleton pattern here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern and here is how to implement it in objective-c: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/