# Using an Array Variable in All Views

Tags: ios, swift

In an app that I am working for, I need array variable that can be used in all `UIView`s. Currently when the array is changed in a view it is stored in the database, and when I need the updated version of the array in the previous view, I use the `viewWillAppear` method and retrieve the updated array from the database. While going to another view by a segue, I use the passing data by `prepareForSegue`, but if I use the back button, or just change the screens via tab bar, I use the `viewWillAppear` and a query.

Is there any way that when the array is created in a view, the data in it will be accessible in all views?

Comment: Of course you can use a singleton but that's generally frowned upon.(see link)  I'll be interested to see what other options are presented given that you don't want to keep saving / fetching the record. (link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Comment: please don't use singletons or any other global data. pass data from view controller to view controller. from there to the view. create a common UIView base class that knows how to handle your data. here I posted code to show how passing form vc to vc can be done easily by subclassing. subclasses views are not covered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979924/passing-data-from-the-firstviewcontroller-to-the-lastviewcontroller/32980270#32980270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Singleton

Singleton is basically a global variable that you can use them in any views, but some developers experience some bugs and difficulties, use it at your own risk, I recommend this method when you're definite that you will use that data a lot (STILL RISKY), **but this method is like goddess of data handling** :).

Create a `NSObject` **subclass** and call it `DataManager.swift` (I call it data manager cause it handle data.) as following:

import UIKit

```
class DataManager: NSObject {
        
   //Store Data Globally
   static var someData: NSArray! //This Boolean, you can choose whatever you want.
}
```

the `static` is what keep your data live.

Now you can store and receive `someData` from anywhere like you handle any data type like this.

```
//Store
DataManager.someData = []

//Receive 
print(DataManager.someData)
```

Comment: Hello Farhad, which one would you offer more, the singleton or global variables that are defined just under the import part. What are the advantages and disadvatages of them?

Comment: Well, you want to use the array in other views and be reliable, then you need singleton. A global variable is safe (not all the time though) cause is out of functions, but more limited. But I recommend singleton. Search for `struct` also, it might help.

Answer (score 2):

As I've stated in my comment, singletons are generally frowned upon for a myriad of reasons. However, there is much debate on this topic:

[What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Having said that, the best way I know to make a variable globally available for the session is by creating a singleton.

```
struct myArray {
    static var data: [Int] = []
}
```

You could set this singleton up to fetch the records using CoreData and store the current working version in a static variable for quick access.

**note:** I am really very curious to see some other approaches.