# Save objects temporarily in iOS

Tags: nsuserdefaults

I have an issue with saving objects temporarily. I have an app that depends 100% on a api. Therefore I don't need to save anything really except for some user defaults which do just fine. But now I need to save some objects temporarily to show them in a checkout page.

The problem here is that I can't save the whole object in the NSUserdefaults as it only accept generic values.

Is there a way to save my objects without using CoreData?

Comment: you can save objects in NSUserdefaults too, bad approach, but you can

Comment: Make your objects conform to `NSCoding` protocol and you will be able to archive them using `NSKeyedArchiver` and store in `NSUserDefaults`. However, if your app is open and you don't need the data on next launch, you don't need to store it anywhere, just keep a reference to the object somewhere.

Comment: It sounds like you use NSUserDefaults to retrieve data in various parts of the app. this is a bad approach. just pass objects where needed.

Comment: The best way to do is NSUserDefault. if and only if you don't want save it even after app delete.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I know. But I don't know initially when I need the object again. I think using CoreData is a "overkill" for this issue and NSUserdefaults being the wrong option. But since there is no chronological way through the app I can't pass the objects in every view.

Comment: Well this sounds like a bad architecture design than. Passing objects is the valid way, as it is the native thing to to in OOP. If it isn't possible in your app, something is very wrong.

Comment: It is possible. But for example if I choose certain things in a view that creates objects of those and puts them in an array. when I go to a different view instead of the checkout I need to pass it to that view first. That means I need to be able to hold the object in every view. A lot of redundant code if you ask me.

Comment: not at all. if you combine inheritance and delegation/callbacks correctly there will be no redundant code at all.

Comment: Could you show me a Swift example? @vikingosegundo

Comment: this is OOP 101. for how to use inheritance to easily pass data through a multi-step wizard, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32980270/106435. Delegation and callbacks should be covered in any Swift course.

Comment: Its not a multistep wizard. That is why your suggested approach won't work. I realized the only way to do is to just use core data or realm and I went for the second. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can save your object in the NSUserDefaults as,
Create an NSObject class of you object, like User.h in this write following code,

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userName;

+ (void)saveCustomObject:(User *)object key:(NSString *)key;
+ (User *)loadCustomObjectWithKey:(NSString *)key;
@end
```

And in User.m file

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
   //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
   [encoder encodeObject:self.userId forKey:@"UserID"];
   [encoder encodeObject:self.userName forKey:@"UserName"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
  if(self = [super init])
  {
      //decode properties, other class vars
      self.userId = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"UserID"];
      self.userName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"UserName"];
   }
  return self;
}

//encoding the DataModel
+ (void)saveCustomObject:(User *)object key:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
    [UserDefaults setObject:encodedObject forKey:key];
    [UserDefaults synchronize];
}

+ (User *)loadCustomObjectWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *encodedObject = [UserDefaults objectForKey:key];
    User *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
    return object;
}
```

For saving your data,

```
User *dataObj = [User new];
dataObj.userId = //User value userid;
dataObj.userFirstName = //user value for user name
//Save user data in UserDefaults
[User saveCustomObject:dataObj key:@"UserData"];
```

and for retrive User data,

```
User *userObj = [User loadCustomObjectWithKey:@"UserData"];
```

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is intended to provide storage for default values; it isn't designed to be used as a data store. The perceived need to do so is usually indicative of deeper design issues that are best tackled head-on, rather than applying band aid solutions to work around them.